# NuGet packages, their DLLs and assembly binding errors

Tags: nuget

Take a package like `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`, it depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` by this line in its `nuspec`:

`<dependency id="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features" version="2.1.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />`

with the `2.1.1` meaning `>= 2.1.1`, in NuGet parlance.

So I take a dependency on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`, version `2.1.1` exactly in my project.

Currently, there is both a version `2.1.1` and `2.2` of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features` in NuGet, so my project ends up with `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 2.1.1` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.2`.

But then, I run my project and I get assembly binding errors, because the actual `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions 2.1.1` DLL depends on `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features 2.1.1`.

Summary: Nuspec says `>= 2.1.1`, DLL is bound to `== 2.1.1`.

This seems to be true for almost all MS packages.

Is this a monumental cock-up, or am I doing something wrong? I'm having to traverse the dependency graphs myself and lock myself to each exact version which each DLL needs, because the nuspecs don't appear to be properly configured.

What's going on?

Example binding error:

> Unable to load one or more types: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features, Version=2.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

(because I've been given `2.2` by NuGet).